# query in mysql to combine parent child relationship

Tags: mysql, parent-child

I am having 3 table in sql, as one parent and one child and one as grand child. :)

[image: dependent tables in mysql]

Now i am trying to write something like this

```
select p.id,p.well_no, c.pidd,c.cd_no, l.pid from lib_cd p,cd c, lib_cd_logs l where l.pid=c.pidd=p.id
```

to display when my id in parent and pidd in child and pid in grand child are same.

Is it possible to write something like above, if yes please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.well_no,
  c.pidd,
  c.cd_no,
  l.pid
FROM lib_cd p
  INNER JOIN cd c ON p.id = c.pidd
  INNER JOIN lib_cd_logs l ON p.id = l.pid
```

If you only want rows where p.id = 19 you can use `where` too

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.well_no,
  c.pidd,
  c.cd_no,
  l.pid
FROM lib_cd p
  INNER JOIN cd c ON p.id = c.pidd
  INNER JOIN lib_cd_logs l ON p.id = l.pid
WHERE p.id = 19
```

Comment: I want to select cells from each table, when my p.id=c.pidd=l.pid to display well no, cd number and the contect of cd,

Comment: Yes, you got that with the first statement @user3521051

Comment: No it is giving all the wells, i mean all the cells in primary table having id 19, 20, 21 etc

Comment: Please edit your question with your specific requirements. Your condition ` p.id=c.pidd=l.pid` is fully satisfied by my statement. If you are expecting different results, you'll need to add the expected resultset and sampledata to your question @user3521051

Comment: Then i think i am making some mistake, Let me think again, please give me some time, i will come to you later, any way thanks for your help